# Assumed role in AWS Lambda, access denied on SSM call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm getting an error in my Lambda function, which calls SSM:

> AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::redacted:assumed-role/LambdaBackend_master_lambda/SpikeLambda is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:redacted:parameter/default/key/api

However, I'm pretty sure I configured this correctly:

Role, with AssumeRole for Lambda (although we know that works from the error message).

```
λ aws iam get-role --role-name LambdaBackend_master_lambda
{
    "Role": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "RoleId": "redacted",
        "CreateDate": "2017-06-23T20:49:37Z",
        "RoleName": "LambdaBackend_master_lambda",
        "Path": "/",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::redacted:role/LambdaBackend_master_lambda"
    }
}
```

And my policy:

```
λ aws iam list-role-policies --role-name LambdaBackend_master_lambda
{
    "PolicyNames": [
        "ssm_read"
    ]
}
λ aws iam get-role-policy --role-name LambdaBackend_master_lambda --policy-name ssm_read
{
    "RoleName": "LambdaBackend_master_lambda",
    "PolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "ssm:DescribeParameters"
                ],
                "Resource": "*",
                "Effect": "Allow"
            },
            {
                "Action": [
                    "ssm:GetParameters"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:redacted:parameter/*",
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
        ]
    },
    "PolicyName": "ssm_read"
}
```

I've run it through the policy simulator and it seems to be fine!

[image: AWS IAM policy sim]

Comment: Seems like a bug in how ssm:GetParameters is validated. When I use `boto3.client('ssm').get_parameter()`, the lambda permissions work as expected, but I get the permissions error you mention when using `boto3.client('ssm').get_parameters()`.

Comment: You need to follow the steps mentioned here to allow the lambda execution role to make read calls to SSM service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76893668/12326605

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Played around with this today and got the following, dropping the s from `ssm:GetParameters` and using `ssm:GetParameter` seems to work when using the GetParameter action. ie `AWS_PROFILE=pstore aws ssm get-parameter --name param_name`. <del>This weirded me out a bit because I cannot find this at all in the iam action docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_ssm.html). However it does seem to work, and ssm is still a bit under documented.</del>
Amazon has updated and moved it's docs. The new [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awssystemsmanager.html) incude both `ssm:GetParameters` and `ssm:GetParameter`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeParameters"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:redacted:parameter/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Under documented, but still better documented than some of the software I use! Thanks!

Comment: Attaching this policy to the role that runs the Lambda solved it for me.

Comment: I had `Action: ["ssm:GetParametersByPath", "ssm:GetParameters", "ssm:GetParameter"]` and it was failing. After removing the first two and leaving only `"ssm:GetParameter"` I got it working

Answer (score 8):

In my case (I used AWS SDK for Go V2), I needed both `ssm:GetParametersByPath` and 
 `ssm:GetParameter` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, only this helped me. Standard error messages are confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same error today. The following Java code caused it when `encrypted = false` and `paramName` referred to an unencrypted parameter

```
    GetParameterRequest request = new GetParameterRequest()
        .withName(paramName)
        .withWithDecryption(encrypted);
    GetParameterResult resultPacket = ssmClient.getParameter(request);
```

The fix was to create the unencrypted parameter request without setting the `WithDecryption` flag - `GetParameterRequest request = new GetParameterRequest().withName(paramName);`

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the command you use in your Lambda.

If you use `boto3.client('ssm').get_parameters(Names=[param1, param2])`, then you need `"Action": ["ssm:GetParameters"]`,

or alternatively when you use `boto3.client('ssm').get_parameter(Name=param)`, you would need `"Action": ["ssm:GetParameter"]`

Answer (score 1):

regarding the confusion ssm:GetParameter and ssm:GetParameters. I attached the policy AmazonEC2RoleforSSM to some user and ran into the same problem, "not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter" because this Policy only has ssm:GetParameters. AWS had a deprecation warning attached to that policy and recommended to use
AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore instead, which has both Actions ssm:GetParameters and ssm:GetParameter. Which then worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

For me I had the path wrong (I was missing the leading `/` on the path name when making the request - it seems obvious but it's easy to miss and worth double checking if you're experiencing this issue.

### ❌ Wrong

```cs
        var getParameterResponse = await _ssm.GetParameterAsync(new GetParameterRequest
        {
            Name = "my-component-namespace/my-parameter",
            WithDecryption = true
        });
```

### ✅ Correct

```cs
        var getParameterResponse = await _ssm.GetParameterAsync(new GetParameterRequest
        {
            Name = "/my-component-namespace/my-parameter",
            WithDecryption = true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `s3:GetObject` and `s3:ListBucket`. To fix the error I had to add the bucket twice in resources and append to one of them a `*`. For example:

```
{
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Action" : [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
      ],
      "Resource" : [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```